# What do I call somebody being a smart ass in Russian?

Tags: лексикон, перевод, одним-словом

What do I call somebody being a smart ass in Russian?

**UPDATE**

Well, I would say smart asses are: arrogant, annoying, think they are witty and funny, but they are not, think everybody cares of what they say, but nobody does, but still have something to say on any topic, think they are messengers of goodness while being just stupid jerks

Comment: I think that your question is answered here: http://lingvopro.abbyyonline.com/en/Translate/en-ru/smart%20ass

Comment: the following is similar, but much ruder: хитрожопый

Comment: Well, I have never heard the word uttered to mean anything than "impudent," but it is out of style to make it clear that one considers someone else to be their lesser and needs to be reminded of that. So наглый.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For the sake of completeness, I'll add the answer here.  The best translation is *умник*. However it's not as rude as *smart ass* in English.

Answer (score 8):

I would say хитрожопый would be the closest translation, I believe it's a modern word and might have been borrowed by translating from English. It is pretty popular.

Comment: житрожопый is not the same as smartass. Smartass is usually somebody who is going out of the way to show others he's smarter than they are and being very aggressive about assuring it. житрожопый means very cunning and adept in getting his way, but not necessarily advertising it openly, but preferring to employ whatever backhanded approach necessary to achieve what he wants.

Answer (score 6):

In Russian it might be easier to say that someone is *being* a smart ass, or *acting* like a smart ass. A very polite or high brow way to translate "He is being a smart ass" would be `Он много о себе мнит`, i. e. "He thinks too highly of himself." Colloquially you could say `Он выпендривается`, or if you wish to be really rude, you could say `Он выёбывается`.

By the same token you could translate "Don't be a smart ass!" as `Не выпендривайся!`

Comment: "Великий и могучий" позволяет из этих глаголов делать существительные — *выпендрёжник*, *выебонщик* или, например, *чувак с выебонами*.

Answer (score 1):

There's a verb for being a smartass - *умничать*. However I can't think about a noun except for already noted умник, which is not widely used and is not as strong as "smartass". One could also say something like "*сильно умный, да?*" which would be like "you're a smartass, aren't you?" if expressed with proper attitude :)

I think the best way to convey the idea is to use verbs - *умничать* or *выпендриваться* mentioned in Dima's answer.

Answer (score -2):

In context someone young who found unusual solution in difficult situation. For example brought bottle of Vodka without having any money.
 - Ай да Васька, ай да сукин сын!

Comment: This this not the same as "smart ass".  That English saying is pretty much always used sarcastically, when somebody is trying to be/do/say something smart, but in reality it looks/sounds/turns out to be a very lame attempt.  The context of an unusual solution in a difficult situation doesn't apply here.

Comment: Aha! I thought it is actually not sarcastic. For describing lame attempt you can say: 
ironically : Ну ты Профессор (с улыбкой) или выражение - Факир был пьян и фокус не удался.

Comment: -1 this is just completely different.